# QuadraticMinimizer always returns a non-sensical answer

Tags: scala-breeze

I'm having trouble with the QuadraticMinimizer- every time I execute it I get errors that are non-sensical. I've looked at the scaladoc and the code and I am just not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

I have the following code:

```
    val lBounds:DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector(Array(Double.NegativeInfinity, 5.0, 0.1, 50.0, 50.0))
  val uBounds:DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector(Array(Double.PositiveInfinity, 500.0, 100.0, 99000.0, 99000.0))

  val inputMatrix:DenseMatrix[Double] = breeze.linalg.csvread(file=new java.io.File(getClass.getResource("/input/zip06latlong.csv").toURI), skipLines=1)

  val y = inputMatrix(::, 0).toDenseVector
  val X = inputMatrix(::, Seq(1,2,3,4,5)).copy.toDenseMatrix
  val T = X.toDenseMatrix.t

  val gram = (T * X)
  val b:Transpose[DenseVector[Double]] = y.t * X

  println(gram)
  println(b.inner)
  breeze.linalg.csvwrite(new java.io.File("grammatrix.csv"), gram)
  val minimizer:QuadraticMinimizer = new QuadraticMinimizer(rank(gram), ProjectBox(lBounds,uBounds))


  val coeffs =  minimizer.minimize(gram, b.inner)
  println(coeffs)
```

here's what the gram looks like:

```
    279.0      628207.0       1461245.0        1024.0     729.5      
628207.0   1.569309427E9  3.414471724E9    2449533.0  1755536.5  
1461245.0  3.414471724E9  1.2324155401E10  5511816.0  3846583.0  
1024.0     2449533.0      5511816.0        3980.0     2786.0     
729.5      1755536.5      3846583.0        2786.0     2092.75
```

and the b vector is:

```
2.917264069193999E8, 7.294450468242601E11, 1.585917338779061E12, 1.131888709844E9, 8.260072757806E8
```

when I execute the code I get:

```
DenseVector(-12171.118011368422, -424.79971124882286, -9.565028484748783, 49.3827769217138, 49.536905925364195)
```

Which is below the lower bounds specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please add the H (gram matrix) and y (linear term) as well so that I can test it out ? Also the initialize pattern is for advanced users (like Spark ALS for which I wrote the solver) but you can use the simple pattern as follows (I used your bounds):

```
val lb = DenseVector(Array(Double.NegativeInfinity, 5.0, 0.1, 50.0, 50.0))
val ub = DenseVector(Array(Double.PositiveInfinity, 500.0, 100.0, 99000.0, 99000.0))

val n = 5

val ata = new DenseMatrix[Double](5, 5,
  Array(4.377, -3.531, -1.306, -0.139, 3.418,
    -3.531, 4.344, 0.934, 0.305, -2.140,
    -1.306, 0.934, 2.644, -0.203, -0.170,
    -0.139, 0.305, -0.203, 5.883, 1.428,
    3.418, -2.140, -0.170, 1.428, 4.684))

val atb = DenseVector(-1.632, 2.115, 1.094, -1.025, -0.636)

val qpSolverBounds = new QuadraticMinimizer(n, ProjectBox(lb, ub))
val result = qpSolverBounds.minimize(ata, atb)
println(s"Bounds test $result")
```

I am getting result as DenseVector(-33.02749751949581, 5.0, 0.1, 50.0, 50.0) which does not look non-sensical.

Please don't change the default maxIter since this control is given for flows where absolute convergence is not necessary. Let the solver choose the maxIter.

Comment: The gram matrix I'm using can be computed by taking columns 1:4 of the input and multiplying them by their transpose, I'll add the original to the question, though it's several hundred rows for the 4 vectors

Comment: Please add only the gram matrix and the linear term..if you have 5 variables, gram will be 5 x 5 matrix (not that big)..Also the linear term should have 5 terms in it as well...Those are the H and y that should be send to minimize

Comment: Your comment tells me what the problem is, I think. My gram matrix is like 279x279, so apparently I'm constructing it incorrectly.

Comment: Here's the gram matrix... (it has the same problem)
3.497096141589097, 7.294450468242473E11,1.5859173387738567,1.13188870983905,8.260072757785255
7.294450468242473,1.569309427E9,3.414471724E9,2449533.0,1755536.5
1.5859173387738567,3.414471724E9,1.2324155401E10,5511816.0,3846583.0
1.13188870983905E9,2449533.0,5511816.0,3980.0,2786.0
8.260072757785255E8,1755536.5,3846583.0,2786.0,2092.75

Comment: I am not sure how many variables your QP has...if it has 5 variables H will be 5x5, y, lb, ub will be vector of length 5...if the problem has 279 variables, H will be 279x279 and y, lb, ub will be vector of length 279...The problem you want to solve is 0.5x'Hx + y'x s.t lb <= x <=  ub...Looks the message you are getting is not that descriptive and it is not guiding you towards the right issue...I would like to put a descriptive error message once we figure out the solve issue for your problem...

Comment: well, I think that may be the nub of the problem right there... I'm not quite sure what to do to reduce my 279 element vector for y down to 5 elements? Should it be the cos of x*y for each vector?

Comment: gram: 
279.0      628207.0       1461245.0        1024.0     729.5      
628207.0   1.569309427E9  3.414471724E9    2449533.0  1755536.5  
1461245.0  3.414471724E9  1.2324155401E10  5511816.0  3846583.0  
1024.0     2449533.0      5511816.0        3980.0     2786.0     
729.5      1755536.5      3846583.0        2786.0     2092.75 

and the following b: 
2.917264069193999E8, 7.294450468242601E11, 1.585917338779061E12, 1.131888709844E9, 8.260072757806E8)
I get
-12171.118011368422, -424.79971124882286, -9.565028484748783, 49.3827769217138, 49.536905925364195) which are below the lower bounds

Comment: The gram matrix that you provided has a high condition number 1.0751e+09...QuadraticMinimizer uses a proximal algorithm and such high condition number will affect convergence. Can you do a feature scaling to improve the condition number of the gram matrix by running a zscore normalization on your features ?

Comment: The following brings me close to optimal but you can see I have to lower the tolerances and increase the maxIter. Feature scaling will help you. The problem is heavily ill conditioned.  val qpSolverBounds = new QuadraticMinimizer(n, ProjectBox(lb, ub), maxIters=400000, abstol = 1e-8, reltol=1e-8) val result = qpSolverBounds.minimizeAndReturnState(H, b)println(s"Bounded Quadratic minimization iters ${result.iter} converged ${result.converged} output ${result.z}")

Comment: iters 246692 converged true output DenseVector(-1057654.0153513495, 5.0, 0.1, 50.0, 50.0) The iteration count of 246K is too high...Mosek solution is (-1057710.543614, 5.000000, 0.100000, 50.000051, 50.000054)